# Exchange Management Console freezing!

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm using Exchange 2007 and I have been trying to add an alias to a user but every time I apply the changes a window will open called Microsoft Management Console with a progress bar but it doesn't seem to end.

I haven't made any changes to it and it seems rather odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the normal remedy of rebooting the server/workstation you are trying this on?  I know it would suck to do if it is the Exchange server itself.

What about installing the Exchange Management tools on a different computer and seeing if you can get it accomplished there?

Comment: It's on the Exchange server itself, I don't really want to reboot it, but I can do tomorrow evening. 

I'll try setting up the Exchange Management tools on my computer and see what that does.

Comment: I installed it on mine but he doesn't seem to work properly, I can see all the mailboxes I've created. But it doesn't let me make changes

Comment: Try adding it through the Exchange Powershell and see if it still hangs up or not.  Since you said "add an alias" I'm guessing you mean additional SMTP address:

$mbx = get-Mailbox testmbx;
$mbx.EmailAddresses += "newaddr@example.com";
$mbx | set-Mailbox

(where testmbx is the mailbox you want to change)
If you meant changing the actual alias itself that is a different command.

Comment: Yes thats right, I'll try that command shortly. If the command fails to work what does it suggest is broken?

Comment: If that fails then there should be an error associated with the shell script that will point you in the right direction at that point.